# Signing the Header and Payload with json private key in C#

Tags: json, key, token, private, signing

I have to generate a Client assertion string signing with the json private key.

I have the private key in the private.json file.  How do I use the private key in the file to sign the Header and payload?

Except the signing part, I have managed to get the other things to work.  Following is the code I use for getting the Signed Client assertion string

```
 public string GetSignedClientAssertion()
{
    var header = new Dictionary<string, string>()
     {
          { "typ" , "JWT"},
          { "alg", "ES512"},
          { "kid", "TST_Staging" }
     };
        
    string token = Encode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JObject.FromObject(header).ToString())) + "." + Encode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JObject.FromObject(GetClaims()).ToString()));
     var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
       var filename = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Private.json");
         string data = File.ReadAllText(filename);
    string key = Encode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
    byte[] databyte = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
 
    //-----I am stuck here on how to sign the token with the Private key from the private.key file
    //---the method used for SignData does not work
    string signature =  SignData(token, data);

    signature = Encode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signature));

    return signedClientAssertion = string.Concat(token, ".", signature);
    
}
```

Private.json has something like the following

```
{
        "kty": "EC",
        "d": "AfJ_hlRFCP0g2PghjghjghjtryrtytyFpbALpoG0gqh9tyaSv8JIZuhKYOgvbAzkI6pi2gdCce3fvWb5csiL24PiS9Ke5CKlh3QyW-YOO",
        "use": "sig",
        "crv": "P-521",
        "kid": "TST_Staging",
        "x": "ADRSCG8Acsqj6SlShpEJYa9UhA7ojghjgjK4eUVHj9CDqbH4j2_F84j7qtK4fdH94xGzYqQwV0rLfJrAISknoudPQm743H",
        "y": "AYnLkWp3Up69WQoc-kZ8ugvSiCNChMiBra3jLHmSotDdzSJ6MgMCokfRdHsfsF-z4VAGq3zam1Z604_rC5N9xrtyrtyufV",
        "alg": "ES512"
    }
```

Can someone point out how to sign the token with the Private key will be much helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to find the solution myself. I am using EC Json public and private keys.  Previously I was using the Algorithm ES512 which had some issues while decrypting the JWE response from the server, so I had changed my JWT key algorithm to ES256 and with this encryption and decryption works perfectly with Jose.JWT.

I have been struggling for more than a month to find a solution for the EC Json Public and private key Encryption and Decryption.  All the solution available out there was for PEM key method only and nothing much for the Json EC keys. It took me a lot of time find the necessary pieces and put them together and make it work. I am providing the entire code for the page where the encryption and decryption happens, so that someone might find it useful.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Text;  // For class Encoding
using System.IO;    // For StreamReader
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using Jose;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Web;
using Jose.keys;
using Stream = System.IO.Stream;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public partial class holding : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string ClientID = "mlDBKnXXXXXTYRTYRTYyYdmzFGD6HcBPsHZ2W";
    string RemoteURL = "https://www.example.org";
    string RemoteTokenAppend = "/token";
    string RedirectURL = "https://www.exampleabc.com/holding.aspx";
    //-----private key for Encrypting the token
    string PrivateKey = @" 
        {
            ""x"": ""4kELRTR545GDGDGtvilOLrtr5luaQaWgaTlpqUf7o"",
            ""y"": ""iCyNdwX73FWKJTjn1Q19gdjEILKjEILK3Y_XwgY3Y_XwgY"",
            ""d"": ""wiYrwNa5SgBNgdqRtSMpaUvRmipaBJ6hfmL1CUMpwlQ"",
            ""kty"": ""EC"",
            ""crv"": ""P-256""
        }";
    Dictionary<string, object> PrivateKeyHeader = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "typ", "JWT" },
            { "kid", "TST_SERVER" },
            { "alg", "ES256" }
        };
    //----Public Enc key for Decrypting the JWE token from the remote host
    string PublicKey_Enc = @" 
        {
            ""x"": ""_ylhMfdVwaRrLx8HL8z7X1ixVkk2rbpwD9oU-uAqyhE"",
            ""y"": ""aCRo4kY2dTl7wZXjsp2NJyF9Tcmzk1XZN5ueJWNq7Lk"",
            ""d"": ""Jz9aEpbt_4aKL5FVdCLlux7U-Ubt_4aKL5VdCLLTR2Y"",
            ""kty"": ""EC"",
            ""crv"": ""P-256""
        }";

    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(RemoteURL + RemoteTokenAppend);
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
        request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        var postData = "client_assertion_type=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer");
        postData += "&client_id=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ClientID);
        postData += "&grant_type=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("authorization_code");
        postData += "&redirect_uri=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(RedirectURL);
        postData += "&code=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["code"]);
        postData += "&client_assertion=" + EncryptTokenJose();

        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "ISO-8859-1");

        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        try
        {
            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            var responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
            var response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            //---Decrypt the Response from Remote
            string JoseRes = DecryptTokenJose(response.ToString());
            //---close the response reader
            responseReader.Close();
            Response.Write("<br><br>Payload = " + JoseRes + "<br><br>");
            //---Get the json string and values from the decrypted Token
            JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(JoseRes));
            var sData = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize<payload>(reader);

            //----Sample Payload
            //---- Payload = { "sub":"s=S775566X,u=c57acrtereb8-d102-455a-860a-ae7dretef4b8d","aud":"mlDBKnGyYfgdgdmzwx770mqXKb6HcBPsHZ2W","amr":["pwd","swk"],"iss":"https:\/\/www.exampleabc.com","exp":1637810980,"iat":1637810380,"nonce":"TJtv85f586sTgxjUlFm5"}
            //----get the sub from Payload
            string sub = sData.sub;

            Response.Write("<br><br>Sub = " + sub + "<br><br>");
            //---Get the list array of sub to extract the IC
            string[] subList = sub.Split(',');

            //---Get the first item of the array to get the IC
            Response.Write("<br><br>NRIC = " + subList[0] + "<br><br>");

            //---Retrieved IC value will be s=S775566X, so replace s= to "" to get the exact NRIC value and set the Session value
            Session["NRIC"] = subList[0].Replace("s=", "");

            //---if Session["RedirctPage"] is set then go to that page
            if (Session["RedirctPage"] != null)
                Response.Redirect(Session["RedirctPage"].ToString());
            else
                Response.Redirect("Register_uat.aspx");

        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {

            using (WebResponse response = ex.Response)
            {


                string ErrorString = "Error from the Server:-----<br><br>";
                HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)response;                   
                using (Stream data1 = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(data1))
                {
                    ErrorString += reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Response.Write(ErrorString);
                }

                
            }
        }
    }

    public string EncryptTokenJose()
    {

        const uint JwtToAadLifetimeInSeconds = 60 * 2; 
        DateTime validFrom = DateTime.UtcNow;
        long exp = ConvertToTimeT(validFrom + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(JwtToAadLifetimeInSeconds));
        long iat = ConvertToTimeT(validFrom);
        //---Payload string
        string payloadStr = "{\"aud\":\"" + RemoteURL + "\",\"exp\":" + exp.ToString() + ",\"iss\":\"" + ClientID + "\",\"iat\": " + iat.ToString() + ",\"sub\":\"" + ClientID + "\"}";
        //---get the Private key to form the public key
        JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(PrivateKey));
        var jwk = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize<JWK>(reader);
        var publicECCKey = EccKey.New(Base64Url.Decode(jwk.x), Base64Url.Decode(jwk.y), Base64Url.Decode(jwk.d), usage: CngKeyUsages.KeyAgreement);
        string token = Jose.JWT.Encode(payloadStr, publicECCKey, JwsAlgorithm.ES256, extraHeaders: PrivateKeyHeader);
        return token;
    }

    public string DecryptTokenJose(string Res)
    {
        var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = Res;
        Dictionary<string, string> sData = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
        string AccessToken = sData["access_token"].ToString();
        string TokenType = sData["token_type"].ToString();
        string IdToken = sData["id_token"].ToString();

        Response.Write("<br><br>" + IdToken + "<br><br>");
        //---get the Public key Enc to decrypt the JWE token
        JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(PublicKey_Enc));
        var jwk = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault().Deserialize<JWK>(reader);
        var publicECCKey = EccKey.New(Base64Url.Decode(jwk.x), Base64Url.Decode(jwk.y), Base64Url.Decode(jwk.d), usage: CngKeyUsages.KeyAgreement);

        //---get the decrypted token
        string token = Jose.JWT.Decode(IdToken, publicECCKey, JweAlgorithm.ECDH_ES_A128KW, JweEncryption.A256CBC_HS512);

        //----todo: Verify the signature of the decoded JWS token

        //----5 parts token with dot(.) as separator
        string[] toklist = token.Split('.');
        //----get the 2nd item of the list which will have the Payload with User IC details
        string Payload = toklist[1];
        //----decode the payload to bytes and from bytes to readable string
        var base64EncodedBytes = Base64Url.Decode(Payload);
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);

    }

    public static long ConvertToTimeT(DateTime dt)
    {
        return (long)(dt - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds;
    }

    public class payload
    {
        public string sub { get; set; }
        public string aud { get; set; }
        public string iss { get; set; }
        public string exp { get; set; }
        public string iat { get; set; }

    }

    public class JWK
    {
        public string x { get; set; }
        public string y { get; set; }
        public string d { get; set; }
    }
}
```